# Why are posts from custom post type not displayed in "category" archive?

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, archives

I've created multiple custom post types which should share "category".

Creation is done like this:

```
 $args = array(
        'label'               => __('MyPostType', 'key'),
        'description'         => __('MyPostType', 'key'),
        'labels'              => $labels,
        'supports'            => array('title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'trackbacks', 'revisions', 'custom-fields'),
        'taxonomies'          => array('category'),
        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'public'              => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'menu_position'       => 5,
        'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-admin-tools',
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'can_export'          => true,
        'has_archive'         => 'techblog',
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'capability_type'     => 'post',
        'rewrite'             => $rewrite
    );

register_post_type('myposttype', $args);
```

This works like expected and I'm able to use categories globally.

**The Problem**

The categories archive only shows posts from "post". If there is no post it only says "nothing found".
Within the single posts meta information the posts categories are listed. I can click them, and get a "nothing found" page.

Unfortunately the documentation says nothing about this. Do I need to do something else? I thought this should work out of the box.

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to add in your CPT to the categories archive page?  Or do you want a separate categories archive specifically for your CPT?

Comment: @socki03 I want one archive page for the category, which lists all posts (from different post types).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to hook into the query because the category archive page explicitly only includes the 'post' type and nothing else.

```
function namespace_add_custom_types( $query ) {
  if( (is_category() || is_tag()) && $query->is_archive() && empty( $query->query_vars['suppress_filters'] ) ) {
    $query->set( 'post_type', array(
     'post', 'myposttime'
        ));
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'namespace_add_custom_types' );
```

Modified from [this article](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/make-archives-php-include-custom-post-types/) on CSS Tricks.